# Why doesn't the "if statement" with numbers in the if statement not working and not running and just stopping after the statement in python 3.7.2?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a python script to make random dice plus numbers and a random dice that can increase the amount of dice rolled. Think D&D 5e.

I have tried changing variables but it seems that no matter what I try it is all around the if statement that is causing the problem.

```
    rolls = 2
    critrolls = 4
    FDMG = 6
    DMG = 0
    Tohit = random.randrange(12, 32)
            if Tohit == "31":
                while str(critrolls) > str(0):
                    DMG = random.randrange(1, 9)
                    FDMG = FDMG + DMG
                    rolls = int(critrolls) - 1
                print("Your to hit is", Tohit)
                print("Your Damage is", FDMG)
            elif Tohit <= 30:
                while str(rolls) > str(0):
                    DMG = random.randrange(1, 9)
                    FDMG = FDMG + DMG
                    rolls = int(rolls) - 1
                print("Your to hit is", Tohit)
                print("Your Damage is", FDMG)
```

I want it to be able to based on the number from the Tohit variable to control the amount of dice rolled. The idea of this is on a 31 roll it will roll 4 dice instead of 2.

Comment: 31 is an _int_, "31" is a _str_

Comment: please, indent the code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tohit = random.randrange(12, 32)` assigns `Tohit` to an integer, but you are doing a string comparison in `if Tohit == "31":`, change it to `Tohit==31` and the code should work :)

In addition, you would want to change your `while str(rolls) > str(0):` to `while rolls > 0` and y to make it an integer to integer comparison, similarly change `while str(critrolls) > str(0)` to `while critrools > 0`

Also your `while critrools > 0` is an infinite loop, since `critrolls = 2` and `2>0` will result in an infinite loop, since you never change `critrolls` value, you need to update that in the loop, perhaps do `critrolls = critrolls - 1`

Making all those changes in mind, your updated code might look like

```
import random
rolls = 2
critrolls = 4
FDMG = 6
DMG = 0
Tohit = random.randrange(12, 32)

#Change to int to int comparison
if Tohit == 31:
    # Change to int to int comparison
    while critrolls > 0:
        DMG = random.randrange(1, 9)
        FDMG = FDMG + DMG
        #Perhaps you need to decrement critrolls here to break infinite loop
        # Change to int to int operation by removing int typecast
        critrolls -= 1
    print("Your to hit is", Tohit)
    print("Your Damage is", FDMG)
elif Tohit <= 30:
    # Change to int to int comparison
     while rolls > 0:
        DMG = random.randrange(1, 9)
        FDMG = FDMG + DMG
        # Change to int to int operation by removing int typecast
        rolls -= 1
     print("Your to hit is", Tohit)
     print("Your Damage is", FDMG)
```

Comment: So when I tried this the script just stopped working. Do you know why? There is more code than this but the rest works fine.

Comment: Thanks that was the source of the problem thank you for the help on the problem! I had it so that the rolls variable was subtracted from critrolls. This caused a problem just as you had said that it was a loop.